# Pyplot's savefig on Windows: Permission Error

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, permissions

*I've found a few similar questions, but this is - to my knowledge - not a duplicate. The other once mostly deal with a folder without permission to write on*

On my Windows 7 machine, I am working with pyCharm and git for Windows. There is some Python script (under version control) which is supposed to create and save a figure:

```
plt.savefig('filename.pdf', bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```

This works very nicely - but only once. After that, I get an `IOError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  - snip - 
    return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "(...)\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 2333, in print_pdf
    file = PdfFile(filename)
  File "(...)\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 400, in __init__
    fh = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myfile.pdf'
```

The error somehow appears to be in the file. pyplot seems not to have the permission to write over the already existing file. If I delete the previously generated file, it works (once).

Using the Git cmd, I can do `ls -al` and get

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername 197121    12927 17:00 myfile.pdf
```

which all appears to be correct. I'm somewhat stuck here, and I usually does not have any problems with writing over existing images with matplotlib. What can I do?